# JavaScript won't add values to array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have written a script that returns values. When I log the variable containing the values, it shows them, and they are correct. Then, no matter how I try, concat, push, equals, etc. when I attempt to add the values to an array, then immediately log the contents of the array, those values are not there or undefined. Here is my code, or at least a subset of it.

```
displayRange: function () {
    if( app.selectedObject !== undefined && app.selectedObject.movement !== undefined && app.selectActive === undefined ) {

        // holds rage
        t.rArray = [];
        t.oArray = [];
        app.selectActive = true;
        t.obj = app.selectedObject;

        // amount of allotted movement for unit
        t.len = t.obj.movement * 2;

        // loop through x and y axis
        for ( x = -t.len; x < t.len; x += 1){
            for ( y = -t.len; y < t.len; y += 1 ){

                // return cost of each movement
                t.hl = this.calcRange('x', x, y );

                // if movement cost is less then or eual to the allotted movement then add it to the range array
                if ( t.hl.move <= t.obj.movement ){
                    // find obsticles

                    t.ex = t.hl.origin.x + x;
                    t.wy = t.hl.origin.y + y;
                    t.obsticle = this.findObsticles(t.ex, t.wy);        

                    // get the number of offset movement from the obsticle
                    if ( t.obsticle !== undefined ){
                        t.offset = app.settings.obsticleStats[t.obsticle.obsticle][app.selectedObject['type']];
                        if ( t.offset !== undefined ){
                            // make an array of offset values, starting point, plus movement, and the amount of offset beyond that movement
                            t.oArray.push(this.obsticleLogic( t.ex, t.wy, t.mx, t.my, t.offset ));
                        }
                    }
                    // add all values to array
                    t.rArray.push({ x: t.ex, y: t.wy, type:'highlight'});
                }
            }
        }

        offsetArr = app.offsetArray( t.rArray, t.oArray );
        for ( l = 0; l < offsetArr; l += 1 ){
            app.map.highlight.push(offsetArr[l]);
        }

        for ( i = 0; i < t.oArray.length; i += 1 ){
            app.offset.push(t.oArray[x]);
        }

        console.log(t.oArray);
        console.log(offsetArr);
        console.log('offset:');
        console.log(app.offset);
        console.log('highlight');
        console.log(app.map.highlight);

        window.requestAnimationFrame(app.animateEffects);
    }

    return false;
},
```

I have set app.map.highlight = [];
in the app.map area. Same with app.offset.

They have been declared, they are just in a different object.

I can't understand why it won't add the values to the array. I log them and see them, then directly after call array push, and it sets everything to undefined. Why would this happen?

The only reason they are being looped through to try and get them into the array is because that's the last thing I tried.

Comment: can you drop this into a working jsFiddle?  It might be easier to understand and work with.

Comment: Ive never used JsFiddlel,  wouldn't know where to begin.. but, my assumption is it must be some scope issue, since it iwill set the values within the function, but wont set them into another object... its just very confusing for me because similar code executes and stores varables in outside arrays no problem.. im brain dead to it right now though, I cant do it anymore.. right now

Comment: Yeah, I'm sure there is some scoping issue.  [Here is JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) .  All you do is put your javascript in the javascript area and then you can put html in if you want.

Comment: I fixed i, thank you though!

Comment: I would suggest you post your answer in case anyone comes back.  You can accept your own answer too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe I had an issue with conflicting variable names, I renamed some of them and it started working.